# Step by step solution of an Indefinite Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I had this on my test, I just couldn't get it, after solving it a lot.
$$\int\left\{\frac{\log x-1}{1+(\log x)^2}\right\}^2\,dx=\,?$$

I have tried substituting $\log(x)=t$ and then
$$
\int \frac{(t-1)^{2} e^{t} d t}{\left(t^{2}+1\right)^{2}}=\int\left\{\frac{\left(t^{2}+1\right)}{\left(t^{2}+1\right)^{2}}-\frac{2 t}{\left(t^{2}+1\right)^{2}}\right\} e^{t} d t
$$
and then, applying the by parts rule,
$$
=e^{t}\left(\tan ^{-1} t-\frac{1}{t^{2}+1}\right)-\int e^{t}\left(\tan ^{-1} t-\frac{1}{t^{2}+1}\right) d t
$$
after that I can't get ahead.

P.S.- All Curly brackets used here are normal brackets, not the ones used in fractional part. Thanks to @ParclyTaxel for pointing it out.

Comment: I don't know how to use LateX so I just uploaded the image. Sorry!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.    If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @DeepJ please show us what you have tried so far,where you are stuck....etc

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore, I have edited the post to show all of you where I am stuck.

Comment: Why the downvote? I am asking, so that I can improve.

Comment: I thought that $\{\cdot\}$ was the fractional part function.

Comment: Ohh!! No! I am Sorry! I didn't specify that.. Thankyou for pointing it out.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving the [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 No, you didn't change the meaning of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $1+\log^2x$ is squared and appears in the denominator, we might try an antiderivative of something over $1+\log^2x$ because of the quotient rule:
$$\frac d{dx}\frac f{1+\log^2x}=\frac{f'(1+\log^2x)-f((2/x)\log x)}{(1+\log^2x)^2}$$
The numerator contains only $\log$s, so $f$ must cancel the $\frac1x$ of $\frac2x\log x$. So $f$ might be $x$; we check and it works, and the answer is
$$\frac x{1+\log^2x}+K$$

Comment: Can I mark two answers as correct to the same question?

Comment: @DeepJ Please mark my answer as correct. You can only pick one.

Comment: Always the same old good trick ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 5):

we have a result $$\int e^x(f(x)+f'(x))=e^x f(x)+c \tag 1$$ this ie very easy to prove by intgration by parts. You have already done the difficult part of splitting the integral to $$\int e^t\left(\frac{1}{t^2+1}-\frac{2t}{{(t^2+1)}^2}\right)dt $$Now if $$f(t)=\frac{1}{t^2+1} \implies f'(t)= \frac{-2t}{{(t^2+1)}^2}$$  which is of form (1).......

Comment: Yes! The form (1) was taught to us.. I just couldn't see it. Thks @AlbusDumbledore

Comment: @DeepJ you are welcome!

Comment: Your answer was equally helpful for solving the question, but I can only mark a single answer as correct.

Comment: @DeepJ never mind the +15 rep is nothing compared to the joy of helping someone,i am not going to sit up and fight for that :) cheers-

Comment: @DeepJ. On the site, most people want to help and are happy when they can . Increasing reputation is not a driving force !

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore. Thanks for your last comment !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I didn't know that! It's really a good thing if that's the case!